# CSS not expanding

Tags: css

Why is the parent div not expanding to fit the inner divs?

```
<div style="width: 800px; border: 1px solid black; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
<div style="float: left; width: 500px; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
    Menu
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 500px;">
    text goes here
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C7MHY/1/

Answer (score 1):

Because the inner divs are floating. 
You may add a "clearer" (an element with CSS property `clear` set to `left` or `both`) after the floating divs to achieve what you want.

Alternatively, you can add `float: left` to the outer div. All floating elements inside another floating element are "cleared automatically".

See http://jsfiddle.net/vovkss/WcSyM/

Answer (score 0):

Because the inner divs are styled as float. To overcome this, you have to add another inner div like that:

```
<div style="width: 800px; border: 1px solid black; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
<div style="float: left; width: 500px; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
    Menu
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 500px;">
    text goes here
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

For further reading:
[MDN: float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)
[MDN: clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to explain, but if you put display: table on your parent DIV works.

```
<div style="display: table; width: 800px; border: 1px solid black; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 500px; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
        Menu
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 500px;">
        text goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to clearing the floats (as mentioned in other answers)...

alternatively, you could also add the rule

`overflow:hidden` or `overflow:auto` to the parent div.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/C7MHY/17/)**

Answer (score 0):

There's no height for the parent div, try using height:auto.